# Is there a way to give a component a child?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

For the following razor:

```
<DxGrid @ref="EffortGrid"
        CssClass="dx-datagrid"
        Data="@(((OrgDashPageModel.OrgModel)contextOrg.DataItem).Efforts)"
        AutoCollapseDetailRow="true"
        PageSize="10"
        PageSizeSelectorVisible="true"
        PageSizeSelectorAllRowsItemVisible="true"
        PageSizeSelectorItems="@(new[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 })"
        KeyboardNavigationEnabled="true">
    <Columns>
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Subject" FieldName="@nameof(OrgDashPageModel.EventPageModel.Subject)" />
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Type" FieldName="@nameof(OrgDashPageModel.EventPageModel.Type)" />
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Date" FieldName="@nameof(OrgDashPageModel.EventPageModel.When)" />
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Location" FieldName="@nameof(OrgDashPageModel.EventPageModel.Location)" />
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Hosts" FieldName="@nameof(OrgDashPageModel.EventPageModel.Hosts)" />
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Owner" FieldName="@nameof(OrgDashPageModel.EventPageModel.Owner)" />
    </Columns>
    <DetailRowTemplate Context="contextEffort">
        <SignupGrid/>
    </DetailRowTemplate>
</DxGrid>
```

I want to turn the `DxGrid` into a component. But, I want this part to be not only optimal, but to have it with no detail component, or one of two different components.

```
<DetailRowTemplate Context="contextEffort">
    <SignupGrid/>
</DetailRowTemplate>
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
<EffortGrid>
    <DetailRowTemplate Context="contextEffort">
        <SignupGrid/>
    </DetailRowTemplate>
</EffortGrid>
```

Where it knows to put the elements inside it after the `</Columns>` element?

---

Based on @mxmissle answer below, it works. But it requires one extra bit of work.

The razor file. Note the `DetailRowDisplayMode="DetailRowMode"` in it:

```
<DxGrid Data="@EventList"
            PageSize="5"
            DetailRowDisplayMode="DetailRowMode"
            CssClass="dx-datagrid">
        <Columns>
            <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Type" FieldName="Type" />
            <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Date" DisplayFormat="g" FieldName="StartDateTime" />
            <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Hosts" FieldName="Hosts" />
            <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Owner" FieldName="Owner" />
        </Columns>
        <DetailRowTemplate Context="contextEffort">
            @ChildContent
        </DetailRowTemplate>
</DxGrid>
```

And the code behind:

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

private GridDetailRowDisplayMode DetailRowMode => ChildContent == null
    ? GridDetailRowDisplayMode.Never
    : GridDetailRowDisplayMode.Auto;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with DxGrid so I cannot verify this will work or not, so in theory you could:

EffortGrid.razor

```
<DxGrid>
    <Columns>       
    </Columns>
    <DetailRowTemplate Context="contextEffort">
       @ChildContent
    </DetailRowTemplate>
</DxGrid>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
<EffortGrid>
  <ChildContent>
    <SignupGrid/>
  </ChildContent>
</EffortGrid>
```

Comment: You're probably right, but `DxGrid` almost certainly uses the modern first render registration mechanism, so coding an abstraction through a `RenderFragment` might just blow it up.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis & mxmissle - it works. But with limitations to inside only specific nodes. It can be inside `<DetailRowTemplate>` but I don't think I can design it so it also will accept there being no `<DetailRowTemplate>` at all. I'll update as I learn more.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis & mxmissle yep it works. Required one other detail specific to DxGrid which I added up above. Thanks